# MySQL Table UNION ISSUE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, union

I'm trying to unite two tables in MySQL, the query I'm using is:

```
SELECT qa_invoicesitems.item_code, qa_invoicesitems.item_unitprice,    qa_invoicesitems.item_subtotal, qa_invoicesitems.item_discount, 
qa_invoicesitems.item_total 
FROM qa_invoicesitems   
RIGHT JOIN qa_invoicesitems_returnlog USING (item_code) 
WHERE invoice_code = 17
UNION
SELECT qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_code, qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_unitprice, qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_subtotal, 
qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_discount, qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_total 
FROM qa_invoicesitems_returnlog 
LEFT JOIN qa_invoicesitems USING (item_code) 
WHERE returnlog_code = 9
```

But I can not behold the desired result.

A graphical example ..
[image]

Anyone have any idea how I can get this result?
  **NOTE:** qa_invoicesitems_returnlog Replaces the data.

The codes: 1234, 1585, 23 are taken from (qa_invoicesitems_returnlog), because they exist in both tables, the rest are simply displayed.
[image]

Comment: So let me see if I understand the question. You want to query the two tables, and where a row exists in both return only the row from the second table?

Comment: Exactly, if the (item_code) is found in both tables, then be replaced by the row of the second table

Comment: Could you edit the original question to make it clear what you want?

Comment: I only need to show the rows found in both tables using the column (item_code) in preference to the second table and add what are not without repeated. Thanks

Comment: So, what you want is a) all the rows from the first table (with `invoice_code = 17`, and b) those rows from the second table (with `returnlog_code = 9`), excluding those rows from the second table whose item_code already exists in the output from the first table.  Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, it be replaced by the row of the second table if found :)

Comment: First you said, "exactly", then you said "it be replaced by the row of the second table if found".  So, do you exclude rows from the second table that are in the first, or exclude rows from the first table that are in the second?  Or, another way, if the same item_code appears in table 1 and table 2 would you expect to see the table 1 row or the table 2 row?

Comment: Sorry if I do not explain very well, please see the third image,
 code (1234) is found in both tables then takes the record (qa_invoicesitems_returnlog)

 When the record is in both will be replaced by (qa_invoicesitems_returnlog)

 Any difference whether or not any of the tables need to display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your comments & your image, I'm going to say you want:

- all the rows in table 2 where `qa_invoicesitems_returnlog = 9`
- all the rows in table 1 where `invoice_code = 17`, except for those rows w/ `item_id`'s that are already present in the output from table 2.

So, writing that out as a union, give you:

```
SELECT qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_code as item_code, 
       qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_unitprice as item_unitprice,
       qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_subtotal as item_subtotal,         
       qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_discount as item_discount, 
       qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.item_total as item_total 
FROM qa_invoicesitems_returnlog
WHERE qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.returnlog_code = 9
UNION
SELECT qa_invoicesitems.item_code as item_code, 
       qa_invoicesitems.item_unitprice as item_unitprice,
       qa_invoicesitems.item_subtotal as item_subtotal,         
       qa_invoicesitems.item_discount as item_discount, 
       qa_invoicesitems.item_total as item_total 
 FROM qa_invoicesitems   
 WHERE qa_invoicesitems.invoice_code = 17
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM qa_invoicesitems_returnlog qir2
                   WHERE qir2.returnlog_code = 9 
                      and qir2.item_code = qa_invoicesitems.item_code)
```

The key is the `NOT EXISTS` clause that excludes from the results from table 1 (`qa_invoiceitems`) that are already present in the output from table 2 and have a matching `item_code`.

Comment: You are my hero, you end up with a small error (and qir2.item_code = qa_invoicesitems.item_code) 
 but the query returns the data I need. +REP

Comment: You're welcome.  The error was that an s was missing from `qa_invoicesitems`, yes?  Just fixed that typo.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a UNION?  I think the following is equivalent to your query:

```
SELECT qa_invoicesitems.item_code, qa_invoicesitems.item_unitprice,
       qa_invoicesitems.item_subtotal, qa_invoicesitems.item_discount,
       qa_invoicesitems.item_total
FROM qa_invoicesitems RIGHT JOIN
     qa_invoicesitems_returnlog
     USING (item_code)
WHERE invoice_code = 15 or returnlogcode = 8
```

The LEFT and RIGHT joins are doing the same thing because the tables are reversed.

Comment: I set the WHERE statement to this (WHERE invoice_code = 17 AND qa_invoicesitems_returnlog.returnlog_code =  9), but still can not get the rows I need

Comment: I believe this query is equivalent to your original query.  However, it does not do exactly what you want.  How are you determining duplicates between the tables?